# (JS) Wait until web3 has been established before running function

Tags: web3js

I'm using an event listener for "DOMContentLoaded" to hopefully wait until my web3 instance has been established. Unfortunately, this does not work as expected and in my `getHash()` function web3 has yet to be instantiated. What's the proper way to listen for when web3 has been defined?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./web3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./setup_web3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./get_hash.js"></script>
<body>
    <h1>Transaction Hash Fetch.</h1>
    <p>Here is the hash for "Transfer(address,address,uint256)"</p>
    <script>
        window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
            getHash();
        });
    </script> 
    <div id="output"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I solved it. I used the observer pattern.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./web3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./Web3Manager.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./Hasher.js"></script>
<body>
    <h1>Transaction Hash Fetcher.</h1>
    <p>Here is the hash for "Transfer(address,address,uint256)"</p>
    <script>
        const manWeb3 = new Web3Manager();
        const hashOutput = new Hasher("Transfer(address,address,uint256)");
        manWeb3.subscribe(output);
        manWeb3.connect();
    </script> 
    <div id="output"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Where `Hasher` looks like this

```js
class Hasher {
    constructor(hashable) {
        this.hashable = hashable;
    }

    run() {
        console.log("Preparing to hash transaction.");
        var hash = web3.utils.keccak256(this.hashable);
        console.log("Hashed transaction ="+hash);
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = hash;
    }
}
```

And `Web3Manager` alerts the hasher after it's connected.

```js
class Web3Manager {
    constructor() {
        this.observers = []
        this.isConnected = false;
    }

    connect() {
        window.addEventListener('load', () => {
            if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
                console.log('Web3 Detected! ' + web3.currentProvider.constructor.name)
                this.setIsConnected(true);
            } else {
                console.log('No Web3 Detected... using HTTP Provider')
                window.web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/<api>"));
                this.setIsConnected(true);
            }
        })
    }

    subscribe(f) {
        this.observers.push(f);
    }

    unsubscribe(f) {
        this.observers = this.observers.filter(subscriber => subscriber !== f);
    }

    setIsConnected(status) {
        this.web3 = status;
        this.notify();
    }

    notify() {
        this.observers.forEach(observer => observer.run())
    }
}
```

Hope this helps someone in the future!

Comment: They do not recommend to connect when loading the page but to add an explicit button, see https://docs.metamask.io/guide/getting-started.html#connecting-to-metamask.

Comment: @Ismael This looks like it's for account info, not for connecting to web3?

Comment: I don't think so, you cannot have access to web3 without enabling an account. They want the user to be aware when an webapp request access to metamask (for security reasons).